# How to get authenticated user data with angularJS and PHP backend

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working with angularJS and PHP backend, I established an authentication and I want to know how I can get the authenticated email and use it to select other data from database in other controllers. I tried to work with sessions by reading some PHP lessons and I applied some examples but it seems that the way is different between PHP and angularJS +php backend. This is the login file:

login.php

```
<?php  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$passwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->passwd);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   passwd= "'.$passwd.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;

  }
```

I want to use the authenticated email to fetch data in other controllers with other web services, I don't know how to recover the email and password

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "?" AND   password= "?")';
```

How can I do please! Thanks in advance

Comment: Before you start doing that, learn about SQL injection (http://bobby-tables.com) and how to prevent them. As a next step, stop saving passwords in plaintext in your database. Use `password_hash()` and for verification `password_verify()` function. You can find how they work by simply using google.

Comment: ok  Twinfriends Thank you

Comment: First you need to call your served file (locally or not) via the $http service in Angular. In that request, you'll pass the params of your user (see the doc for $http) to verify its legitimacy and to be able to make the verification in your php file. Once you've made your verification, you'll return something in that php file into angular, and get the data you need in Angular. Then you can store the response of that request into a variable called $scope.user (for example). You can make a service (see angular services) to help using your object through your application. Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you , I know how to do firsts steps, know I will search for the remaining: store response in controller and use it in other web service. I will read about your suggestion§. Thank you